# Emulator Skipping frames

Tags: android, performance, android-emulator

I am using the Android Emulator (details below) and I was getting the message in the log: `I/Choreographer: Skipped xxx frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread`, where "xxx" would be anywhere from 500-600. The issue is on my only Activity and I commented out all of my code with the exception of the `OnCreate` method. I only have 2 EditTexts and 2 buttons in my only Activity and I get the error when I try to type into an EditText. After making a new Emulator and giving it almost double the amount of RAM (2536) and increasing the VM Heap size to 74 from 64, the "xxx" amount of frames skipped jumped from 500-600 per message to about 1100-1200 per message. I really want to use the Android Emulator, so please do not recommend another Emulator but how do I fix this issue?

Device Details:

- Nexus 6
- API 23
- Target: Android 6.0 (with Google APIs)
- CPU/ABI:   x86_64
- Size on Disk: 1 GB
- RAM: 2536 MB
- VM Heap: 74 MB
- Internal Storage: 400 GB

Comment: Why do you really want to use the Android Emulator......?

Comment: I am using Firebase as my back end and setting Genymotion up with Google APIs does not work for me. The files never finish downloading. @Razgriz

Comment: Don't you have an actual device to test on....? Also, emulator skipping frames isn't "lethal" anyway?

Comment: I am an Apple user and this is my first app using a Back End for Android @Razgriz . I also am unable to use the app with the buildup of skipped frames. Eventually the app just closes, not crashes but just exits.